# Control WPF Navigation History

Tags: wpf, navigation, state

WPF Automatically remembers control state for Dependency Properties with the Journal metadata flag.

On top of this you can implement IProvideCustomContentState to provide your own custom state information.

However, I can't find a way to do ONLY custom state and turn off the automatic Dependency Property state tracking.  I want to do this because I know exactly what state should be remembered for my Pages and how that state should be re-setup.

Is there a way to tell WPF not to journal the properties of my controls?